# Zybook 3.8 LAB: Read values into a list

Tags: python

Write a program that reads a list of integers into a list as long as the integers are greater than zero, then outputs the values of the list.
Ex: If the input is:

10
5
3
21
2
(a negative 6 goes after this but I don't know how to get it to show)

the output is:

```
[10, 5, 3, 21, 2]
```

You can assume that the list of integers will have at least 2 values.

This is the code I used

```
user_numbers = int(input())
lst = []

while True:
    user_numbers = int(input())
    if user_numbers > 0:
        break
    lst.append(user_numbers)

print(user_numbers, ', ')
```

my output ends up like this:

```
5 ,
```

I have tried to change the " if user_numbers > 0" to "user_numbers < 0" but all that does it produce a EOF Error.

Comment: `if user_numbers < 0:` ?

Comment: read your comment wrong when I do it that way it gives me an error

Comment: then edit your question to provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to **stop** when the number is negative, so the loop should break when `user_numbers < 0`, not when `user_numbers > 0`.

Also, the first line should be removed because you read an integer but don't add it to the list.

Finally, you want to print the whole list at the end, not the last number, so it should be `print(lst)`.

Updated code:

```py
lst = []

while True:
    user_numbers = int(input())
    if user_numbers < 0: # We replace '>' with '<'
        break
    lst.append(user_numbers)

print(lst)
```

Comment: This is all I get back. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
    user_numbers = int(input())
EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Comment: it's the same error. I don't believe so

Comment: 10 5 3 21 and 2

Comment: yes sorry I forgot the negative. So the number I work with are 10 5 3 21 2 and -6

Comment: it skips 10 and prints the rest of the numbers so it looks like this when executed [5, 3, 21, 2]

Comment: Just like you said i forgot to remove the user_numbers = int(input()) on the first line. That got ride of the issue